# How to create a div on a specific location of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-places-api

I want to create a popup/div at a specific location on the screen like image below

[image]

Say it should start after edit button and its position should be exactly the same as shown in the image.

Comment: Please give the reason to downvote the qus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpde7by8/) that I made for you. This is quite simple to do. This example requires JQuery though, but if you fiddle around: I'm sure it can run without it as well :)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box1">
    This is box 1
    <br />
    <button onClick="openEditBox();" id="editButton">Edit</button>
</div>
<div id="box2" style="display: none;">
    This is the edit box...
    <br />
    Edit stuff goes here...
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#box2");

    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});

function openEditBox() {
    var editButtonPosition = $("#editButton").position();
    $("#box2").css({top: editButtonPosition.top + 20, left: editButtonPosition.left});
    $("#box2").show();
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#box1 {
    background-color: #AAA;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
#box2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;

    z-index: 1000;

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Run it live on JSFiddle to test it out and see how it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/fpde7by8/

*About the down votes: People here seem to hate simple questions... But I don't see the problem. Everyone was a beginner at some point.*

Answer (score 1):

The popup div should be the child of the first div(maybe the Edit button's div) , set the first div position:relative, the popup div position:absolute, so the popup's position is relative to the first div,then you can use code like this : 'left:50px;top:50px;'